# How to pass URL variable into APEX report?

Tags: oracle-apex

I have created an APEX application which needs to take a parameter form the URL, for example P1_ID -> 'ORCL'.

```
DB1:8080/apex/f?p=101:1::::P1_ID:ORCL:
```

On the page i have a "Classic Report (based on Function)" which should use this parameter.

```
declare
  l_sql_stmt varchar2(64);
  l_id varchar2(8) := :P1_ID;
begin
  l_sql_stmt = '
    select
      *
    from
      T1@' || l_id;
  return l_sql_stmt;
end;
```

When i try to save, it gives me the error:

```
ORA-01008: not all variables bound
```

How can i use this URL parameter in the PL/SQL function?

Answer (score 1):

Apex tries to parse the statement when you save the report. It does this so it could generate the correct columns and give them a name.
Your query can however only be parsed at runtime. You should therefor set the option "Use Generic Column Names (parse query at runtime only)" below the region source. Apex will then generate generic columns (col01,col02,...) with similar generic names, and they'll be filled with what the select statement returns. If you then want dynamic column names, you'll have to set the option in the report attributes to generate them through a plsql function too.
As a sidenote then, it's bad form to write a `select *`. Always provide the actual column list. And if you're trying to make a single report be able to run a query on each table on each dblink, I'd reconsider.
If your report holds a certain set of columns, and table T1 exists on your local db and a remote db, you may also simply create two classic reports and display them conditionally. This allows you to use apex to the fullest.

If you want to set up a URL to link to a page and set the session state of an item, you need to use the correct URL syntax. Your URL is wrong, as you are passing in a page item name as a clear cache parameter and ORCL as a page item name. [Read the documentation on the URL syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E59726_01/doc.50/e39147/concept_url.htm#HTMDB03017). 
Furthermore, you're not passing in a session id. If you use this URL within an active session it will start a new session, and the user will need to login again. You may want to provide some additional information on how and where you are defining this URL.

Comment: The `select *` was an example, as i use clearly defined column names in the select. My problem is though using the variable in the statement.

Comment: @Geo ok, so what about the rest of my post? As I understand, you're not able to save the report with the source you describe. That's normal because there is no session state for a "P1_ID" item when you save the report and apex tries to parse the statement to collect metadata. That's why you get the error you describe.

Comment: Thanks, i have checked and and modified the columns as you indicated. Now at least i can save the application. The variable binding problem still exists though.

Comment: @Geo I edited in a short piece about URL syntax. Your URL is not correct,  which is likely the culprit in not setting P1_ID with a value. Double check the docs and make sure your values are in the correct places.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter `P1_ID` need to be recognized by the PL/SQL program.

- Create a page item `P1_ID` with type as `Hidden`
- If required add condition `Item not null` for item `P1_ID` for PL/SQL in Processes

**Update:**

Set of things to note in your PL/SQL:

> 1. `l_sql_stmt` assignment

`l_sql_stmt =` should be replaced with `l_sql_stmt :=`, otherwise it will throw `PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "=" when expecting one of the following:`

> 2. You can't return a value from anonymous block

PL/SQL script you have is a anonymous block you can't return value from these blocks. otherwise you will hit `PLS-00372: In a procedure, RETURN statement cannot contain an expression` error.

> 3. Create a function which can take value of P1_ID as argument

You can create a function which can take the value of `P1_ID` as argument and pass it externally.

Example:

```
create or replace function getQueryString (osid varchar2)
return varchar2
is
  l_sql_stmt varchar2(64);
begin
  l_sql_stmt := '
    select
      *
    from
      T1@' ||osid;
  return l_sql_stmt;
end;
/
```

Sample execution:

```
var P1_ID varchar2(50);
SQL> begin
  2  :P1_ID := 'xyz';
  3  dbms_output.put_line(getQueryString(:P1_ID));
  4  end;
  5  /

    select
      *
    from
      T1@xyz

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Also, ensure that `P1_ID` is listed in `Page Items` section of your APEX application console.

Comment: Thanks for the lengthy explanation. I missed the ":=" just while simplifying the example. Also the report seems to generate nicely (when i say explicitly `l_id varchar2(8) := 'ORCL';`) even with an anonymous block. I am still facing the initial issue though, assigning the variable. Now i am using in the report source `return TESTFUNCTION (:P1_ID)` but i still get the not bound error. Under `Page 2 - Regions - Content Body - Report - Items` appears P1_ID as `Hidden`.

Comment: i don't think the problem is in the report/query itself but in my lack of knowledge on how to take the variable from URL and do anything with it (for instance display it in a `Text Field`)

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this was that I changed this

```
l_id varchar2(8) := :P1_ID;
```

to

```
l_id varchar2(8) = v('P1_ID');
```